# How to use code in androidTest directory of another module

Tags: android, testing, gradle

I add two modules in my AndroidStudio project:

```
app-base
|
|----src
      |____androidTest
                |________MyTestBase.java          

app
|
|----src
      |____androidTest
                |________MyTest.java
```

Some common test class are defined in app-base's androidTest, and are used in app'androidTest.

I have tried to add the following code in app's build.gradle:

```
    evaluationDependsOn(':app-base')

    compile project(':app-base')

    androidTestCompile project(':app-base')
```

I have include both app-base and app in settings.gradle, the output of **gradlew projects** is:

```
Root project 'MyProject'
+--- Project ':app-base' 
+--- Project ':app'
```

No compile error by this way, but when I Run MyTest in ide, it said class MyTestBase is not found.

Do you know what's wrong? Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you define an appropriate *settings.gradle* file? What is the output of `gradlew projects`? Take a look at the [Gradle documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) for more information on how to setup multi-project builds.

Comment: Having a dependency on another project's test code is definitely atypical. You'll have to explicitly depend on the projects testCompile configuraiton. Try `androidTestCompile project(path: ':app-base', configuration: 'androidTestCompile')`.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49436559/android-multi-module-test-dependency

Answer (score 29):

I've been looking for a solution to this for a while and finally found something that works for me.

This will allow you to put common testing classes in another module.

```
android {
    ...

    sourceSets {
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += ["${project('match the module name that is currently in the dependencies').projectDir}/src/androidTest/java"]
    }
}
```

So for the example above it would probably look something like

```
androidTest.java.srcDirs += ["${project(':appbase').projectDir}/src/androidTest/java"]
```

Comment: by the way, it works but Android Studio does not recognize the file from the other module.  only annoying because of the red squiggly lines underneath the import stmt of that file.

Comment: @sudocoder, The red squiggly line sounds like that module isn't compiling properly under a normal build. What's the error? Are you missing a dependency in that module

Comment: If it works when running the test it means it can compile correctly when doing an android test compile and is not related. This code compiles the code under the original modules dependencies and not the dependencies of the module the code resides in.

Comment: Best solution if you have few classes to be shared instead of creating a separate module, thank you :)

Comment: The solution worked for me.  I see the red squiggly lines reported by @sudocoder , My project has two modules that depend on a third module which contains the shared test code.  ONE of the dependent modules has no red squiggly lines whereas the other dependent module does.  The one that's ok is called :app and the one which has the squigglies is :appgrab.  I don't know of any other differences.  I can get rid of the red squigglies by adding `androidTestImplementation project(":app")` to build.gradle for :appgrab even though :appgrab and :app are supposed to be independent.

Comment: I decided to use the other solution from @ben75 instead because I'm afraid the red squigglies will make this solution confusing to others who will maintain it long-term.

Answer (score 15):

I suggest you the following strategy : create a new module `test-utils` and put `MyTestBase.java` in the main sources of this module.

```
test-utils
|
|----src
      |____main
             |________MyTestBase.java
```

Then you add this `test-utils` as a test dependency in all modules where it is required

```
androidTestCompile project(':test-utils')
```

Comment: Yes, I ever think about the solution. I think that works. But then I need to add a new module for just a few classes. That's not acceptable. But thanks any way:)

Comment: IMHO a new module is not a big thing. Alternative solutions are : duplicate code in every module or define multiple source directories for androidTest with some relative path like : `../app-base/src/androidTest/java/` (IMHO both of them are worse)

Comment: I tried this approach but could not get it working. in the `instrumentantiontest` module gradle file I used 'compile' statements since the sources are in `main' . Everything compiles, but when running all instrumentation tests, it cannot find any test. When specifically ruinning a test method, the test errors with a ClassNotFound exception

Comment: I think this answer is only helpful if the code being shared is really Utils needed in multiple other modules. If base module contains some test structures/helpers that are specific to the "actual" code in base module, then organizationally, it would make sense to keep those test structures in base module.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I'm getting an "Unresolved reference: BaseTest" error.

Comment: As mentioned, only useful if you want to use some sort of "utils", however if you have for example mock factories of models that you need that are generated in their own module, you'll fall in something as the OP questioned.

Comment: I tried this method - but since I have multiple custom classes used in testing, I couldn't move only the class imported in the test cases, because it led to circular dependencies. To avoid that I'd have to move a large number of files to test-utils and that's a too large refactoring for my small change

Comment: This solution worked pretty well for me.  It wasn't that hard to create a separate module because Android Studio helped me through the menu option File -> New -> New Module.  I'm using Android Studio 4.0.1.

Comment: Advice: convert all of the `androidTestImplementation`, etc. to `implementation` in the build.gradle for the :test-utils module.  Initially I forgot to do this when I moved my test code from the application module to the :test-utils module.

Comment: Advice: if any of the shared test code refers to R.id's, for example `R.id.myButton` in  `onView(withId(R.id.myButton)).perform(click())`, then it's problematic to move that code as-is to :test-utils.  I think `R` is generated at compile-time and it's a class that's specific to the application module.  So one solution is to pass it as a variable into a function which uses it.  In my case R came from a third module shared by my two application modules.  So I fixed it by prefixing `R.id.myButton` with the third module's package, like `com.myco.sdk.R.id.myButton`.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. @AutonomousApps did you resolve this?

Comment: This method is much nicer than messing with the srcDirs. It's less likely to go wrong if any paths change and code indexing will work properly.

Also `androidTestCompile` should be `testImplementation` or `androidTestImplementation` as necessary in current versions of gradle.

Answer (score 3):

With little change in Stimsoni's answer, this is finally worked for me.
I added this to my app gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    test.java.srcDirs += ["${project(':app-base').projectDir}/src/test/java"]
}
```

Comment: The first version `androidTest.java` + `/src/androidTest` is for instrumentation tests (androidTest) and the second `test.java` + `/src/test`  is for pure unit tests (test)