# Android multi module test dependency

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

*With Android Studio 3.0 / android_gradle_version = '3.0.1' / gradle-4.5*

Let's say I have two android modules

```
module-base
module-a
```

When I want to access sources from module-base in module-a , I just need to write this in my
module-a.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':module-base')
}
```

**But, what if I want to access test sources from module-base in test of module-a**?
*Here does not work approach like above*

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation project(path: ':module-base')
}
```

I found lot of advices (few years old) which says something like

```
compileTestJava.dependsOn tasks.getByPath(':module-base:testClasses')
testCompile files(project(':module-base').sourceSets.test.output.classesDir)
```

or
`testCompile project(':module-base).sourceSets.test.classes`

But no one from mentioned works. There is always something wrong from the compiler point of view :-/

**Can you someone help me how to create Android test code dependency between two modules?**

Comment: Did you find a solution? same problem for me

Comment: I have the same issue too ...

Comment: Workaround I have been using is here (look at module-test-utils) https://github.com/kotomisak/image-analyzer-android

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone else ends up here, one way to accomplish this is to define the target module as a source set. Let's assume **test-mdoule** is the module we want to import stuff from, we can do it this way:

```java
android {
    sourceSets {
        // non-instrumental test example
        test {
            java.srcDir project(":test-module").file("src/test/java")
        }
        // instrumental test example
        androidTest {
            java.srcDir project(":test-module").file("src/androidTest/java")
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://jonnycaley.medium.com/sharing-test-code-in-a-multi-module-android-project-7ce4de788016

Comment: This solution works fine with Gradle, but Android Studio Electric Eel still marks the shared code as Unresolved reference.

Comment: Work fine in  Electric Eel

Answer (score 10):

Actually I find just workaround for this. Don't use test sources from **module-base** but use sources from test related module **module-testutils** which is defined like this

```
dependencies{
   testImplementation project(':module-testutils')
}
```

Thus you can share common test code which will be excluded for non-testable apk.

Comment: What exactly is module-testutils? I mean, is it just another module created where you have your classes in src/main/java instead of src/test/java?

Comment: Yeah, for exact working code example I have been using just look at this android project: https://github.com/kotomisak/image-analyzer-android